# Javascript Module Pattern and Jquery live?

Tags: javascript, live, jquery, module-pattern

I am trying to use the [JavaScript Module Pattern](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/3/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth)  and I run into a problem that I am unsure how to get around.

So I have 2 script files as I want to separate my code and make it easier to read.

```
// script 1

var abc = (function (my, $)
{
    my.events = function ()
   {
        // selectors is from my base file(not shown as I don't think it is needed to be shown)
        // my.selectors.createFrm = '#createFrm'
        var createSubmitFrmHandler = $(my.selectors.createFrm).live('submit', function (e)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
        });

   }

   return my;

} abc || {}, jQuery));

// script 2

var abc = (function (my, $)
{
     my.dialogs = {

        addDialog: function ()
        {
            var $dialog = $('<div></div>').dialog(
            {
                width: 580,
                height: 410,
                resizable: false,
                modal: true,
                autoOpen: false,
                title: 'Basic Dialog',
                buttons:
                    {
                        Cancel: function ()
                        {
                            $(this).dialog('close');
                        },
                        'Create': function ()
                        {

                            jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.parse(my.selectors.createFrm)
                            // this is undefined as page loadup no form was found so live did not kick in
                            my.createSubmitFrmHandler.validate().form();

                        }
                    }
            });

            return $dialog;
        },

    return my;
} abc || {}, jQuery));
```

So I am not sure how to make sure that createSubmitFrmHandler is defined and continue what I am doing.

**Edit**

I ended up doing something like this

```
   var abc = (function (my, $)
    {
        my.events = function ()
       {
            // some one time events here
       }

        my.test = function() 
        {
            var add = $(selectors.createFrm).live('submit', function (e)
            {
                e.preventDefault();
            });

            return add;
        };
    }
```

The only thing I am unsure is that if I call up this function over and over will it keep making this object or will it look and see that the live is already bound and won't do any more binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of the module pattern is that Javascript has function scope: variables defined with `var` are local to the function in which they are defined.

```
(function() {
    var foo = 'bar';
    // foo == 'bar'
})();
// foo == undefined
```

Since you define `createSubmitFrmHandler` in the function which you assign to `my.events`, you cannot refer to it outside the body of that function. There are several ways around this. The point of passing `my` to all modules is that they can share secrets through it: you can set `my.events.handler = createSubmitFrmHandler` in the first module, and `my.events.handler` will be visible in the other module since `my` is visible there. You could have `my.events()` return `createSubmitFrmHandler` and reference it that way. If the selector is not a costly one, you can simply calculate the value of `createSubmitFrmHandler` again, and use `$(my.selectors.createFrm).validate().form();` in the dialog module instead of trying to reference `createSubmitFrmHandler`. Whatever suits you.

Comment: @Tgr - Sorry I don't understand what you just said. Don't I have that? $(my.selectors.createFrm).live('submit',..). This literally my first day using the module pattern...

Comment: Do you mean I should have this my.createSubmitFrmHandler.validate().form(); ? If so I tried that and got "my.createSubmitFrmHandler is undefined"

Comment: Updated the answer, hopefully it makes more sense now.

Comment: @chobo2: calling my.test more than once will bind multiple event handlers, but then why would you do that? Since the event handler is live, there is no need to bind it again if e.g. a new form is added.

Comment: @Tgr - hmm well how I have it right now it would do it multiple times but your right of why would you do it more than once. I am trying to figure out how to put code since this is all quite different then how I done it in the past.